# VBA to upload Excel File to Sharepoint. Run Time error '1004'

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint, runtime-error

Hi all I hope you can help. I have a piece of code and what it does is if cell A2 is changed to anything other than "Enter Your Country Here" it finds and replaces all the "Enter Your Country Here" in the workbook with the new value in A2. This part works fine. The issue I am having is that once the cell change happens I also want the workbook to save to our Sharepoint environment. But I keep getting **Run Time error '1004'** on the following line

```
SaveAs Filename:="http://teamspace.merck.com/sites/emea_efpia/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Femea%5Fefpia%2FShared%20Documents%2FEFPIA%20Regional%20Reporting%20Team%2FDispute%20Management%2FDispute%20reports%20per%20market%2FGlobal%20Reporting&FolderCTID=0x012000FA7F4E9565D6274DAF9E871EA008299B&View=%7BB6EF0397-E24C-49DF-92EF-CB7015B60539"
```

If I replace the Sharepoint address with a C drive or local address it works perfectly. Am I missing something? Can my code be amended to allow the workbook to be saved to Sharepoint? My code is below and as always any and all help is greatly appreciated.

CODE

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  ThisFile = Range("A2").Value
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim fnd As Variant
  Dim rplc As Variant

  fnd = "Enter Your Country Here"
  rplc = Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Range("A2").Value
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
  SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Next sht
  For Each cell In Range("A2")
  If cell.Value <> "Enter Your Country Here" Then
  SaveAs Filename:="http://teamspace.merck.com/sites/emea_efpia/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Femea%5Fefpia%2FShared%20Documents%2FEFPIA%20Regional%20Reporting%20Team%2FDispute%20Management%2FDispute%20reports%20per%20market%2FGlobal%20Reporting&FolderCTID=0x012000FA7F4E9565D6274DAF9E871EA008299B&View=%7BB6EF0397-E24C-49DF-92EF-CB7015B60539"
  End If
  Next cell
  Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Activate
  ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

As requested new coding

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  ThisFile = Range("A2").Value
  Dim cell As Range
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim fnd As Variant
  Dim rplc As Variant

  fnd = "Enter Your Country Here"
  rplc = Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Range("A2").Value
  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
  LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
  SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
  Next sht
  For Each cell In Range("A2")
  If cell.Value <> "Enter Your Country Here" Then
  Application.SaveAs Filename:="\\teamspace.merck.com\sites\emea_efpia\Shared%20Documents\EFPIA%20Regional%20Reporting%20Team%2FDispute%20Management\Dispute%20reports%20per%20market\Global%20Reporting\["C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\CRO Countries\" & ThisFile & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM").xlsm]", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
  End If
  Next cell
  Worksheets("SearchCasesResults").Activate
  ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save to a page, not a folder.Try changing the saveas line to:

```
Application.SaveAs Filename:="//teamspace.merck.com/sites/emea_efpia/Shared%20Documents/EFPIA%20Regional%20Reporting%20Team%2FDispute%20Management/Dispute%20reports%20per%20market/Global%20Reporting/[FILENAME.xlsx]" _
 , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: You would probably have to change all the `/` to `\ ` also

Comment: Hi CLR: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I tried the code you supplied but now I am getting another error. Run Time error '438' Have I done something wrong. I also changed the / to / as suggested by Macro Man I get the same error.

Comment: Can you update the question with your coding as you have it now?

Comment: CLR I have added the new coding to the question please note that i removed  `_` from the piece of code you supplied me `/[FILENAME.xlsx]" _ , FileFormat:` as that line of code became red if the `_` remained in. Thank you again for the assistance I also to Macro mans advice and replaced `\ with `/

Comment: But you've replaced the `[FILENAME.xlsx]` with the actual filename (and extension) yes?

Comment: ah no I will try that now. sorry.

Comment: Don't forget, if you're using `FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled` then the filename should end `.xlsm`

Comment: Hi CLR I think I may of misunderstood your last comment. put the file name `ThisFile`and the location into the line that was bugging. This line is now red. have I done something wrong the line now looks like this `Application.SaveAs Filename:="\\teamspace.merck.com\sites\emea_efpia\Shared%20Documents\EFPIA%20Regional%20Reporting%20Team%2FDispute%20Management\Dispute%20reports%20per%20market\Global%20Reporting\["C:\Users\CONNELLP\Desktop\Claire Macro\CRO Countries\" & ThisFile & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM")]", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: I'm assuming from the above that you have a function or variable called `ThisFile` which contains the name of the file you want to write, *without* the file extension. If that's the case then I think this will work - `Application.SaveAs Filename:="\\teamspace.merck.com\sites\emea_efpia\Shared%20Documents\EFPIA%20Regional%20Reporting%20Team%2FDispute%20Management\Dispute%20reports%20per%20market\Global%20Reporting\" & ThisFile & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM") & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False`

Comment: Hi CLR: Nope sorry I entered the code you supplied above without the file extension and still I have the same error. and yes `ThisFile` is a variable declared earlier in the code. It takes the vale in A2 and names the worksheet after it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138739/discussion-between-clr-and-philip-connell).